# Ajax rendering with :remote => true not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, firefox, firebug

My controller actions: **advertisment_controller.rb**

```
class AdvertismentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_advertisment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

  layout 'admin'

  respond_to :html

  # GET /advertisments
  # GET /advertisments.json
  def index
    @advertise_tab = 'active'
    if current_user.is_super_admin?
      @advertisments = Advertisment.all
    elsif current_user.is_admin?
      @advertisments = current_user.mediums.last.advertisments
    elsif current_user.is_agent?
      @advertisments = Advertisment.all.collect{|ad| ad if (ad.discount_rate.present? && ad.discount_rate.discount_provider == current_user.id) }.delete_if{|x| x == nil}
    elsif current_user.is_member?
      @advertisments = current_user.advertisments
    end
  end

  # GET /advertisments/new
  def new
    if current_user.is_agent? || current_user.is_member?
      @advertise_tab = 'active'
      @advertisment = Advertisment.new
      load_ad_components
    else
      redirect_to advertisments_path, flash: {error: 'You cannot create an advertisment'}
    end
  end

  # GET /advertisments/1/edit
  def edit
    @mediums = Medium.all
    @discount_rates = current_user.discount_rates.where(:media_category_id => @advertisment.media_category_id)
    @draft_advertisments = current_user.advertisments.where(:draft => true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  # POST /advertisments
  # POST /advertisments.json
  def create
    @advertisment = current_user.advertisments.new(advertisment_params)
    @advertisment.save
    load_ad_components
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /advertisments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /advertisments/1.json
  def update
    @advertisment.update(advertisment_params)
    load_ad_components
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  # DELETE /advertisments/1
  # DELETE /advertisments/1.json
  def destroy
    @advertisment.destroy
    flash.now[:success] = "Advertisement deleted successfully."
    load_ad_components
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

My **advertisments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(advertisment, :multipart => true, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    // form fields 
    // advertisment is a local parameter  
<% end %>
```

Now, if I submit this `form`, it is requesting the controller `create` method as `html` instead of `js`. 
Also, for `edit`, I've created the link as 
`<li><a href="<%= edit_advertisment_path(ad) %>" data-remote="true">Edit</a></li>`

but when I click on the edit link nothing happens. No ajax call showing in the firebug console. My `application.js` file contains,

```
//= require jquery.min.js
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Whats wrong here? BTW, I've tested the whole edit, create, update, destroy with ajax rendering I've mentioned above in `Chrome` browser, and its working fine. Does anyone have any idea whats wrong with this code in firefox?

N.B. firebug for firefox show me that both the js files (jquery.min, jquery_ujs) are loaded. I've deleted my `browser cache`. But still the same. :'(

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had weird issue with Firefox, using a remote with Ajax on Firefox. I found that if I commented  out //= jquery_ujs from the application.js file, my Ajax rendering worked. This isn't an answer, just a debugging idea.

Comment: @ValAsensio, not working. :(

Comment: That's probably good. It's been awhile since I went through this. If anything else comes to mind, I'll follow up.

Comment: try using `respond_to :html, :js` or remove that line `respond_to :html`